# php paypal adaptive chained payment implementation without leaving my website

Tags: php, paypal

I am tying to use PayPal adaptive chained payment API.

But, my problem is that, i don't want to leave my website for payment.

I want a kind of do direct payment using adaptive chain payment method.

I found api which do this by taking users to PayPal site,

but could not find the one which i want..

Any help would be welcomed..

Can Someone help?

My payment scenario is like this::

users will pay to my website i.e me, then after 3 days my application will redirect this payment to two of my clients parallely..

```
user -> me $100.
```

after 3 days.

```
me->my client1 = $70.
me->my client2 = $30.
```

this all process should be maintained on MY SITE ONLY.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Where are you stuck?

Comment: exactly speaking, i want a paypal adaptive chained payment api where people dont have to go to paypals site for payment and return back.     I want that my users remain on my site and perform payment...

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible because of PayPal's security concerns and fraud protection. Users have to be redirected to PayPal's site in order to complete their transaction.

Comment: paypal provides api for this purpose..
the same thing happens when we perform dodirect payment using paypal's api.